# Liferay do not register deployed portlets

Tags: deployment, jboss, liferay, portlet

We are facing a strange behaviour of our liferay instance. We have about 25 custom portlets/hooks we are deploying as separate 25 war files. Once are deployed one by one everything works fine and liferay register all of them. However once we perform restart of AS (bundled jboss), than only part of portlets is registered/visible in liferay gui. Jboss saying that all of them are properly deployed in logs, even in deployments folder, but few of them are still not visible in liferay. 
Afterwards we have to re-deploy missing portlets manualy to see them in liferay again. We tried to enhance jboss deployment scanner timeout but without any affect. Also log files are without any error which could explain this behaviour.

Could you please advice what may goes wrong?

We are running Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.2 CE GA3 (Newton / Build 6202 / January 15, 2015) bundled with Jboss 7.1.1

Thanks in advance

```
piece of log:
13:15:54,477 INFO [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found sample-portlet.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called sample-portlet.war.dodeploy 
13:15:54,773 INFO [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "sample-portlet.war" 
13:16:32,555 INFO [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'sample-portlet.war#liferay' 
13:16:46,946 INFO [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sample-portlet]] (MSC service thread 1-7) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath 
13:16:46,973 INFO [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /sample-portlet 
13:18:31,336 INFO [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "sample-portlet.war"
```

Comment: What about registration messages of Liferay in the log, everything with `*HotDeploy*`, e.g. `[PortletHotDeployListener] Registering portlets for...`?

Comment: There is no such a *HotDeploy* message for missing portlet. Below are log lines I found in log file.

Comment: First of all: you can edit your query (and format you log). Please post only real answers below. Next: You've got the _HotDeploy_ messages for all other portlets, except the _sample-portlet_?

Comment: Sorry for that log. Yes that is exactly what I ment. With exception that it is not always the same portlet. I have situation when I have lets say 4 portlets, each in separete war file... e.g. portlet1.war, portlet2.war, portlet3.war and sample-portlet.war. When I deploy each single portlet separately, they are running fine. Then I perform restart of jboss and liferay will register only portlet1.war and portlet2.war. Next restart and liferay will register portlet1.war and sample-portlet.war, etc.

Comment: Sounds strange to me. I've got a JBoss with about 20 plugins - no problem during startup. Can you debug and check, if the PluginContextListener is called for every plugin and what he is doing? That is the part where the "registration" of plugins takes place. Another check: Create a `ROOT.war.undeployed` in `deployments`, start the server and remove that file once the server has started. If the problem vanishes it could be a racecondition during registration.

Comment: Thanks for hint Tobias. It seems I found the portlets causing this. I have there two spring portlets running different spring version than liferay has. Once they are deployed while liferay is running they works fine. However once we perform restart then this two portlet are not loaded into liferay .. and rest portlets which follows neither. Now I need to figure out how to convince liferay to load that two portlets properly with spring version used by those two portlets and not with his own.

Answer (score -1):

The issue might be related to war dependency. If your wars depend on each other, you need to declare plugin dependency to make sure the deployment happens in a desired order. Liferay may not give message for unsuccessful deployment. You can declare the dependency in liferay-plugin-package.properties.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunatelly plugins are not dependend on each other.